# Docker Wildfly Image with 32 bit Java

Tags: java, docker, wildfly

As docker by default works on 64 bit. Currently i am not sure how it can work with 32 bit. I wanted to use Wildfly with 32-bit Java to deploy my application. Do i need to create my own image ? or some workaround is there ?

Answer (score 0):

Docker works in 32 bits, but is not officially supported

You can find various 32 bits docker images on the docker hub, see this one for Java

https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudcom/32bit-java/~/dockerfile/

You can create your own image from a Debian 32 bits or any other distribution

Comment: do a Google search of `site:https://hub.docker.com/ 32 bit` in order to find 32 bits docker image

Answer (score 0):

You can run 32bit jvm in docker container, even if container is 64bit.

You just need to make sure that your image uses 32bit JDK.
For that you will probably need to create your own image where you install 32bit JDK. just make sure you install also i686 versions of linux packages to be able to run i686 jvm.

For example on Centos / RHEL / Fedora you need to install following packages:

- glibc.i686
- libgcc.i686
- zlib.i686
- bzip2

To make 32bit jdk work.